# How to remove the smallest term from asymptotic expansion?

Tags: series-expansion, asymptotics

It is well-known that $e^{-1/x}\sim o(x^n)$ as $x\to 0^+$ for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, thus if I do an asymptotic expansion for a function, say $f=1/(1-x)+e^{-1/x}$ as $x\to 0^+$, I expect to receive an answer like $f\sim 1+x + x^2+o(x^2)$. Nevertheless both ***Asymptotic*** and ***Series*** give me results including $e^{-1/x}$, see

> In[1]:= Asymptotic[1/(1 - x) + E^(-1/x), {x, 0, 2}]
> Out[1]:= 1 + E^(-1/x) + x + x^2
> In[2]:= Series[1/(1 - x) + E^(-1/x), {x, 0, 2}]
> Out[2]:= E^-(1/x)+O[x]^3+(1+x+x^2+O[x]^3)

My question is how to remove $e^{-1/x}$ in practice.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: From Calculus,  `E^(-1/x) ` has no Taylor Series Expand for in `Reals`

Comment: @cvgmt You're confusing asymptotic analysis with "Taylor Series Expand", please do not understand me wrong. I am talking about an asymptotic behavior of a function including a $e^{-1/x}$ term.